# H1 in a div class is not working. not sure why

Tags: html, css

i am using .section-title h1 in my css to and align the text to centre but it doesnt work but it surely work if i just use h1 to align text.

```html
<div id="section-title">
    <h1>GET IN TOUCH</h1>
    <p>Make sure to subscribe to this channel</p>
</div>
```

For the CSS I have tried

```css
h1.section-title {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and

```css
.section-title h1
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: section-title is the ID of the H1. So please use # instead of . in your css

Comment: That is because you assigned it as an ID but in your css, you are calling it as a class, thus , there is no such class. Change the `.` to `#` in your css . eg; `#section-title h1`

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

Instead of using Class selector replace with ID selector(#).

```
#section-title h1
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

Option1 using a div class:

```html
<div class="section-title">
    <h1>GET IN TOUCH</h1>
    <p>Make sure to subscribe to this channel</p>
</div>
```

```css
.section-title h1 
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Or option2 using the h1 ID:

```html
<div>
    <h1 id="section-title">GET IN TOUCH</h1>
    <p>Make sure to subscribe to this channel</p>
</div>
```

and

```css
h1#section-title
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Because there are fundamental differences between classes and IDs in html/css. You are using an id so you have to use Id selector.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

'section-title' is the ID of the H1. So please use '#' instead of '.' in your css

```css
h1#section-title
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1 id="section-title">GET IN TOUCH</h1>
    <p>Make sure to subscribe to this channel</p>
</div>
```